# Strange issue with Powershell stopping randomly?

Tags: powershell

I have a set of scripts that run and spit out various bits of output.  Sometimes they'll just stop until I hit enter.  I have nothing in my script that prompts for information from the user.

At first I thought maybe it just wasn't flushing the output, but I've sat and waited to see what would happen and it doesn't act as if it had been processing in the background and just not flushing the output to the console (it would be further along).

The strange thing is that it happens at different points in the script.

Does anyone have any input on this?  Anything I can look at specifically to identify this?  This script will eventually be kicked off by another process and I can't have it randomly waiting and sitting.

Comment: Have you tried on more than one machine? What OS and Powershell version are you running? Can you post some examples?

Comment: Powershell 3 on Win7 64-bit.  I've seen it pause after a copy operation from dir to dir, after a copy operation from dir to UNC, I've seen it pause after a call to PowerCLI to clone a VM, and so forth.  It's extremely random, but what ends up happening is it just sits there until I hit enter, then moves forward.  It doesn't jump forward the way I would expect it to if it had merely been the output not getting flushed, it starts moving forward from the point it was "stuck" and not any quicker than you would normally expect.

Comment: Never seen that behaviour before - post some scripts that do this and point out where it seems to stick please

Comment: Do you have QuickEdit mode enabled by default on PS windows?  If so, are you sure you aren't clicking in the window somewhere--this will pause the script until you hit Enter to "mark" the text to be copied.

Comment: Sounds like a [cross-site duplicate](http://serverfault.com/questions/204150/sometimes-powershell-stops-sending-output-until-i-press-enter-why) to me

Comment: Mathias, that isn't me :)  Tony I do actually have QuickEdit enabled for that console, thank you for that observation.  I didn't realize that was a possibility, I'll check it out and get back with you.  Reply to the question and I'll mark it if that turns out to be the answer :)